# V8 memory usage

Tags: android, node.js, memory, v8

what is the minimum RAM required for running v8 java-script engine.

Is it suitable for limited memory devices. I want to use node.js as embedded sever in android application. Is it a good idea?

Comment: You know that Android uses a Web Browser which uses V8 engine?? This should answer your question.

Comment: I think this is a vague question. Will node.js work on Android, it should work as noted already. Should you use it? That depends on what you are trying to do. If your goal is something that can be accomplished in native code, you should probably go that route as it will likely be more responsive and battery friendly opposed to using higher level languages. If you are just trying to reach across platforms, then maybe an already available tool is what you need.

Comment: `Is it a good idea?` Is it even possible?? Node.js is more then just an application living on top of V8 engine. I don't think it is possible to use it with Android (or any mobile OS) at the moment.

Comment: It is possible to make it work on android. I found some open source projects. I am trying to evaluate some available solutions to run a http server on android. I found that it is possible to use node-js also.. but what are the advantages.. and disadvantages

Comment: basic nodejs server = (libUV + http_parser + v8).. ...but similar behaviour can be achieved by using (boost ASIO + http_parser) ..

Comment: yes.. android chrome browser uses v8.. but it is available for ICS devices only... is it because of its high memory requirement?

Comment: The built-in, default Android browser also has always used V8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

V8 requests memory for the JavaScript heap in 1 MB chunks called **pages**. These are grouped in **spaces** which contain different kinds of objects. There are 7 spaces (from, to, pointer, data, code, cell, map), or 8 if you count large object spac. At absolute minimum you need at least one page per space, so that's 7 MB right there. V8 itself is about 3 MB (at least on ARM, YMMV). Plus, you'd need another 2 MB or so for scratch space. So that's 12 MB in total, at minimum. You'd probably want to have 20-30 MB available in total for normal operation.

All this should fit easily on any Android device. All devices I know of have at least 256 MB of RAM, and you can expect the OS and other apps to use at least half of that. Note that the Android web browser already embeds V8 and has no trouble. The browser's instance of V8 likely has a larger memory footprint than the V8 portion of a Node.js server.

Comment: Generally +1, although I can't agree with the last sentence. A Node.js server which does nothing obviously does not use much memory. But that's not the point, right? Server should *serve* something. And handling connections also eats both CPU and memory. Concluding: some day we will definetly be able to turn mobiles into remote servers, but not today.

Answer (score 1):

First: I would like to know how you embed node.js into a android app.

To your question: The memory usage depends a lot on various compile flags of node.js/V8, the system architecture , so your question could not be answered 100%.

Tweaking the garbage collector behaviour could also be interesting. (It's very roughly: more cpu (do the garbage collection more often) <--> more memory ("waste" more memory and clean up later)

Comment: Yeah, using Node.js in Android would be really interesting. But I doubt it is possible. After all Node.js is **more** then just V8 engine.